# Single component texture with float

Tags: webgl

Is there way to create only a texture having single component float value each pixel?
I want to draw shadow map into texture, I don't want to use the extension for depth format because it is not good for multi buffer drawing.

I know I can use UBYTE RGBA texture and split float value for each colors, but I afraid of performance effect of that solution.

I know there is a texture format gl.RED in OpenGL 4, if there was such texture format it is suitable for this situation.But It seems WebGL don't have such feature.
First I thought gl.ALPHA is that, but it seems different thing. gl.LUMINANCE also seems different thing.

Is there any way to achive single component of float texture in WebGL?

Comment: What leads you to believe that using the `depth_texture` extension is bad for multi buffer drawing?!

Comment: If it was color texture type, it can be used for multiple targets. But, I don't think depth buffer can accept multiple texture.

Comment: You can enable `OES_texture_float` and then create `gl.LUMINANCE, gl.FLOAT` or `gl.ALPHA, gl.FLOAT` textures. Not `OES_texture_float` is pretty much only available on desktop machines not mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pack the float into rgba channels. Just use a standard 8 bit per channel rgba texture.

```
    "vec4 pack_float(float f){",
    "   const vec4 bit_shift = vec4(256.0*256.0*256.0, 256.0*256.0, 256.0, 1.0);",
    "   const vec4 bit_mask = vec4(0.0, 1.0/256.0, 1.0/256.0, 1.0/256.0);",
    "   vec4 res = fract(f * bit_shift);",
    "   res -= res.xxyz * bit_mask;",
    "   return res;",
    "}",
```

and

```
    "float unpack_float(vec4 rgba){",
    "   const vec4 bit_shift = vec4(1.0/(256.0*256.0*256.0), 1.0/(256.0*256.0), 1.0/256.0, 1.0);",
    "   float res = dot(rgba, bit_shift);",
    "   return res;",
    "}",
```

Comment: If I need just rgb(24bit), I can use pack_float(SOMETHING).gba as packed value,right?

Comment: I believe so, but I never tried it. Although if you want 24 bit depth buffer, why not just output to the depth_texture? FYI the multiple render output refers to multiple color textures but you can always output to the depth texture if u have the extension enabled.

Comment: By using multiple render target, I think it will be good for performance. But, depth texture can't attach to ColorTarget right? So, I think I can't use depth texture multi times in the one of draw call.

Comment: You can render to multiple color targets and one depth texture target in one draw call. Use `gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gl.TEXTURE_2D, depth_texture, 0);
        ` for the depth texture.

Comment: I mean I want to render multiple "shadow map" with one draw call if I could. So, I think it is better not to use DEPTH_ATTACHMENT.  I think it is better to draw shadow maps as color buffers.

Comment: @LimeStreem How exactly are you planning to *render* multiple shadow maps in one draw call? You can only have one set of transformed vertex coordinates.